# ¿Como hago una copia de seguridad parcial de una tabla?

Tags: mysql

En una base de datos llamada TEST tengo una tabla llamada CULTIVOS en que uno de sus campos es de tipo numérico y se llama PID.

Esta tabla tiene esta estructura:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE CULTIVOS;
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type                   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| PID      | smallint(9) unsigned   | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| datetime | decimal(13,0) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| value    | float                  | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+----------+------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

La tabla contiene miles de líneas con PID=37. Y me han pasado unos datos sobre el cultivo 37 que supuestamente corrigen los que hay actualmente en la base de datos que están mal. Hay líneas que está mal el datetime, líneas en que está mal el value, líneas con ambos mal y líneas con ambos bien. Los datos que he recibido son completos, si quito lo que había y añado lo nuevo se supone que todo queda bien.
Con lo que mi plan es borrar los actuales datos con PID=37 con :

```
DELETE FROM CULTIVOS WHERE PID=37;
```

Después añadir los miles de líneas con los datos que me han pasado y luego el personal que se encarga de esto me dirá si está bien o vuelvo para atrás.

Para volver para atrás necesito una copia de seguridad pero no puede hacerla de toda la tabla porque :

- Tiene cientos de millones de líneas. Y como siempre esto corre prisa.
- La tabla se va a seguir utilizando y si se decide volver para atrás solo puedo volver para atrás los datos con PID=37, no el resto de la tabla.

¿Cómo hago pues una copia de seguridad de la tabla que contenga solo las filas con PID=37?

Comment: No entiendo ¿por qué hay que hacer un `DELETE` en vez de hacer un `UPDATE` usando los datos con la corrección, los cuales imagino están en una tabla? Si la tabla tiene un id autonumérico que se usa en otras relaciones podría haber problemas. En cuanto a una copia de los PID=37 se puede hacer también creando una tabla a partir de la actual, pasándole ese criterio ([ver aquí](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html)). Queda la duda de saber qué es más eficaz.

Comment: @A.Cedano He editado la pregunta para aclararlo. Se trata no solo de actualizar datos incorrectos, tambien hay datos que se añadieron y que no había que haberlos añadido. El PID es asignado manualmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si podes tener la tabla dentro de la misma base, podés correr un

```
CREATE TABLE tabla_backup
  AS (SELECT * FROM tabla_original where pid = 37);
```

No se que motor usas, pero es el equivalente a crear una tabla con los mismos campos y hacer un insert into ... select ...

EDIT I

Ahí vi que es mysql. MySql soporta "Create Table As".

Comment: Una aternativa interesante esta. En mi caso particular prefiero hacer la copia de seguridad fuera de la base de datos porque no quiero alterar la base de datos de producción. Pero es muy posible que haya situaciones en que sea más conveniente esto.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=tu_usuario --password=tu_password \  
          --no-create-info TEST  CULTIVOS \
          --where="PID=37" > copia_seguridad_CULTIVOS_PID37.sql
```

Explicación:

```
mysqldump        #El comando de volcado de mysql.
--host=ip        #La dirección del servidor de BD. localhost si es en el mismo PC
--user=nombre    #El nombre de usuario con que accedes a la BD.
--password=algo  #La contraseña.
--no-create-info #Hace que no se vuelquen instruccines de creación de la tabla.
TEST             #El nombre de tu base de datos, en este caso TEST.
CULTIVO          #El nombre de la tabla a volcar parcialmente.
--where="cond"   #Una condición. Solo se vuelcan las líneas que cumplen
                 #esta condición.
> nombre_fichero #Redirección de salida para que se guarde el volcado en fichero.
```